# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from tab crashed error when executing from Jenkins CI server

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run my automation tests from Jenkins CI server (built with Gradle), but the browser crashes instantly with the error below. It also crashes when I run gradle test from the console. Now when I am running the same test from the IDE (Idea), everything works just fine. I run the exact same test file, in the exact same directory.
Versions:
Selenium:  3.11.0
Gradle:    4.6
TestNG:    6.14.2
Chrome:    65.0.3325.181
Chromedriver: 2.37

Anyone has any idea what could be causing this?

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.50 seconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'USNBDFV9K12', ip: '10.23.4.80', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at qa.appmanager.ApplicationManager.init(ApplicationManager.java:48)
    at qa.tests.misc_tests.TestBase.setUp(TestBase.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:401)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: post your code!

Comment: This is happening again in Chrome 70.

Comment: This is happening to me in a Python project with Chrome 71.0.3578.80

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from tab crashed (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 2.50 seconds Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z' System info: host: 'USNBDFV9K12', ip: '10.23.4.80', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

The error stack trace clearly shows your *ChromeDriver* binary details are not getting detected back as in :

```
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Though your *chromedriver=2.37.544315* and *Chrome: 65.0.3325.181* are compatible your main issue is **java.version: '1.8.0_131'** which is *ancient*.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u162](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html)
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a system *Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### from tab crashed

*from tab crashed* was WIP(*Work In Progress*) with the *Chromium Team* for quite some time now which relates to *Linux attempting to always use /dev/shm for non-executable memory*. Here are the references :

- [Linux: Chrome/Chromium SIGBUS/Aw, Snap! on small /dev/shm](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853)
- [Chrome crashes/fails to load when /dev/shm is too small, and location can't be overridden](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715363)
- As per [Comment61#Issue 736452](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=736452#c61) the fix seems to be have landed with *Chrome v65.0.3299.6*

Hence you may need to bump up to *Chrome v65.0.3299.6* or later.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I run the test from IDE it uses the same version of Java and works just fine, so there is got to be something else. Anyway, updating to the newest version doesn't hurt.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.20 seconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'USNBDFV9K12', ip: '10.23.4.80', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_162'

Comment: @Igor Check out my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: similar issue for windows containers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959477/selenium-inside-windows-docker-container-fails-with-ff-chrome-session-deleted-b

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Crash issue fix :

This code with launch the browser without any crash.
Make sure, chrome exe is compatible with the current browser.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with Chromedriver version 83.0.4103.39 (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: "Please try..." reads like a debugging experiment proposal, which is more of a clarification question than an answer. As such this should be a comment ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). Please rephrase this into a conditional answer like "If the root cause of your problem is ... then the solution is to  ...".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was getting crashed in my *chromium* due to **DDoS protection**,
[image]

I am able to solve it with the answer provided here [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/60403652#60403652)

Some take aways are,

1. Please check the source html data. With python: `driver.page_source`
2. As mentioned in the linked answer,

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
driver.get('https://www.httpbin.org/headers')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The following actions helped:

1. Put the version of Java 11, in the maven (The same version was indicated for Jenkins when installing it. Java version for Jenkins 11 original from the oracle site, not OpenJDK, and environment variable JAVA_HOME must indicates this version. Jenkins had problems with OpenJDK.).
2. Adding a git ignore file (I forgot to add it at the beginning of the project). Deleting folders in the project folder: target and idea.
   (I also don’t think this is important either .. But I also reopened the project folder in the idea, ran the tests, and chose to save the IML config.)
3. Pushing the changes to the github.
4. In Jenkis, deleting the current assembly of the project. Well, start on a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If the thread-count or data-provider-thread-count is more, decrease the thread-count value in testng file to make room for the session to get created

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).