# Selenium & Heroku: urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, buildpack

Setup:

- **selenium**: 3.141.0
- **python**: 3.6.7
- **heroku-stack**: heroku-18
- **headless-chrome**: v71.0.3578.80 buildpack installed
- **chromedriver**: v2.44.609551 buildpack installed

I'm getting this error when using selenium in heroku:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

I googled but didn't have luck. The error happens at the last line of this code.

---

### **Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36' \
     '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
DRIVER_PATH = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={UA}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server=http://my_private_proxy.com:my_port')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** in **Headless** mode was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Some information regarding the versions of the binaries you are using would have helped us to analyze the error in a better way. However, this issue of **urllib3** can be obseved due to several reasons as mentioned below:

- As you are using *non Windows* OS, the argument **`--disable-gpu`** is not needed as in the discussion [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) skyos...@chromium.org mentioned:

> This flag is no longer necessary on Linux or macOS. It will become unnecessary on Windows as soon as  [SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) gets fixed.

- You can find a detailed discussion in [Lost UI shared context : while initializing Chrome browser through ChromeDriver in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-ini/50148698#50148698)
- Additionally, you can add the argument **`--disable-dev-shm-usage`** to overcome limited resource problems:

  ```
  chrome_options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion on `--disable-dev-shm-usage` in the discussion [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d/50642913#50642913)
- As per [urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799251/urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-error10054-an-exist) this issue was observed when there is some **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.44**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v69-71*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.44 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Heroku is a cloud platform as a service I'm using as server. I updated the version for chromedriver in the post. I don't know how to get the headless version from the server, but being provided by Heroku, must be pretty modern.

I can't do IDE things in Heroku, but I'm doing the changes you told me in the source code, review the binary and driver paths and reboot the Heroku server.

Don't know how to deal with the @Test thing either.

Meanwhile I'm trying, thanks. :-)

Comment: Seems like some of your advice did work. Now I got to a different SessionNotCreatedException: "Session not created from crash tab". I'm working through this now. Thanks.

Comment: @madtyn For the error **SessionNotCreatedException: "Session not created from crash tab"** check the **Update** section within my Answer in the discussion [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from tab crashed error when executing from Jenkins CI server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518157/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-session-not-created-exception-fr/49518339#49518339)