# 'Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer') using Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

The code below is executed in a loop, where 10-15 local .html files are opened and an image of each is saved as a .png.

- Ubuntu Server 16.04
- ChromeDriver  2.41.578700
- Google Chrome 74.0.3729.108
- selenium 3.141.0
- Python 3.6

The first two files are opened and the image is saved, however the rest result in:

> ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

The paths to the files are all correct and changing the order of the images to be saved does not make a difference.

```
def _save_image(html_file_path, png_file_path, h=850, w=833):
    try:
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception("Saving the plot as a .PNG requires *selenium* package to be installed. Please install selenium using *pip install selenium*.")

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    #options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

    if os.name == 'nt':
        chrome_driver_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        chrome_driver_path = chrome_driver_path[:-3] + "chromedriver.exe"
    elif os.name == 'posix':
        chrome_driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
    else:
        raise Exception("OS could not be detected, thus selenium could not be initialised properly.")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(w, h)
    driver.get("file://"+html_file_path)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.save_screenshot(png_file_path + ".png")
    driver.quit()
    time.sleep(5)
```

The time.sleep(5) was added to check if the error was due to the page taking long to load, increased it to 30 seconds and the result was the same. The import statements are within the function due to a technical requirement which will be sorted at a later stage.

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to communicate with the *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- You are using *chrome=74.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v74.x*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v74.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at *Chrome v74* levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt))
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium & Heroku: urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521883/selenium-heroku-urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-con/53717432#53717432)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the version issue. I have upgraded ChromeDriver to 74.0.3729.6 and this has improved the situation, more of the charts are being generated. However, the "('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))" error still occurs, and this is now random (i.e. not for the last x .html files as in the original issue)

Answer (score 0):

This most probably because you are using an older version of chrome driver for new Chrome version.

Download the latest chrome driver for your Chrome from [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)