# Chromedriver timesout while trying to locate a element

Tags: python, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I've deployed a selenium script using python with chromedriver in play on my Heroku server.

EDIT: The driver is configured properly, and it does launch an instance, performs the task. However for the consequent call, the driver is unable to locate the element - then again for the third iteration, it is able to locate the element.

I'm not quite sure if explicit sleep statement would work.

Here is a small snippet from my selenium script:

```
def execute_entry(url,proxy,email):
      try:
            browser = driver.load_chrome_driver(proxy)
            browser.get(url)
            browser.maximize_window()

            browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1040)")
            sleep(5)
            print("Launching browser")

            # check if the page is still available
            try:
                  print("Checking for page")
                  element_present = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comp_firstname"]'))
                  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(element_present)
            except Exception as e:
                  # exit script
                  logging.exception("message")
                  print("Unable to locate element")
                  message = "There seems to be an issue with your registration. Entry is probably closed or their server is not responsive at the moment. Timed out waiting for page to load. Please try again later!"
                  email_ops.send_email(email, 'Entry Status: Error', message)
                  browser.quit()
                  return False

            # register - if page is available
            .....
            .....
            # rest of the selenium script to fill the form details
```

The script is working fine when tested on the local server.

Any idea what could have gone wrong here?

Comment: After a few more trials, it seems like it has no pattern. The solution is not stable.

Comment: I'm having similar problems myself. The scraping is being rejected by the web sites and I try to use proxies and change the user agent headers or is taking too much time or all at the same time. It worked much better locally too, but everything seems harder when deployed in Heroku.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - but with only one of my web scrappers. It works perfectly on my Mac but fails on Heroku every time to detect when the new page has been loaded after completing a login procedure. Same login procedure used on other Heroku-based web scrappers. At a loss to crack the problem.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? I've tried absolutely everything and no matter what permutation of arguments or environment variables I try, it times out when trying to open a URL, load the page and wait on an element to show up. Works perfectly fine on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after some digging I found [this post](http://www.viderman.com/2017/05/selenium-on-heroku.html#c2251670679506324847).

So, apparently, "Google renders different html based on your user-agent". I did the user agent setup as shown in that post, but in python:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36")
```

After that everything worked just fine!

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Generally, answers should be self contained: links can change but the answer stil has to be valid even if the link is broken. If this is not already the case - could you edit your answer such that every info is contained here and a broken link would not impact it?