# selenium chromedriver crash on server (session deleted because of page crash)

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

I've a small script using selenium running in *Docker container* :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

try:
    use_service = True
    path_driver =  os.getcwd() + "/drivers/chromedriver"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

    if use_service:
        print("---> use Service()")
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
        service = Service(path_driver)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver,options=options)


    driver.get(my_url)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "login").send_keys("bar")    
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "pass").send_keys("foo")
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "OK").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    urls = { "04": "https://xxx.xx/xxx/xxx","05": "https://xxx.xx/xxx/xxx",}

    for dept, url in urls.items():
        driver.get(url)
        print(len(driver.page_source))

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR ", str(e))
```

On the server, it's working, but some times in the container, it crash afte on this line "driver.find_element(By.NAME, "OK").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)" :

```
---> use Service()
ERROR  Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=111.0.5563.64)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x556474bfed93 <unknown>
#1 0x5564749cd15d <unknown>
#2 0x5564749b908c <unknown>
#3 0x5564749b8531 <unknown>
#4 0x5564749b75bb <unknown>
#5 0x5564749b7404 <unknown>
#6 0x5564749b5ee2 <unknown>
#7 0x5564749b6682 <unknown>
#8 0x5564749c3b4f <unknown>
#9 0x5564749c47a2 <unknown>
#10 0x5564749d4ba0 <unknown>
#11 0x5564749d8e40 <unknown>
#12 0x5564749b6b43 <unknown>
#13 0x5564749d47dc <unknown>
#14 0x556474a4583a <unknown>
#15 0x556474a2d353 <unknown>
#16 0x5564749fce40 <unknown>
#17 0x5564749fe038 <unknown>
#18 0x556474c528be <unknown>
#19 0x556474c568f0 <unknown>
#20 0x556474c36f90 <unknown>
#21 0x556474c57b7d <unknown>
#22 0x556474c28578 <unknown>
#23 0x556474c7c348 <unknown>
#24 0x556474c7c4d6 <unknown>
#25 0x556474c96341 <unknown>
#26 0x7f92ba72ffa3 start_thread
```

I've try on the same server not using docker, simply install selenium, and it's working.

Informations :

Docker : Linux 40b5ec9c18f9 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

System : Linux valabre-prod23 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 111.0.5563.64

$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839})

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

F.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ERROR  Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
```

...implies that [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) crashed while interacting with the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) client.

You are facing this crash possibly is due to **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to [ChromeDriver v114.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.90/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=114.0* (as per [chromedriver=114.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.90/notes.txt)).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.10.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed with ChromeDriver Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970825/7429447)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from tab crashed using ChromeDriver Chrome Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191325/7429447)
- [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from tab crashed error when executing from Jenkins CI server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49518339/7429447)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm going to check ad update chromedriver and/or google chromedriver.