# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id using Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing some code using Selenium, and at one point I make 7 requests, all to different websites. For the first one, this works fine. However, for others, I get a session ID error. I think that my browser is configured correctly, as I do get results from the first website. I have tried to put a WebDriverWait in between the requests, but to no avail. I think the websites might be blocking my requests. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

I'm sorry if this is something stupid or if I'm doing anything wrong, I'm quite new ^^

Thanks in advance!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cena/PycharmProjects/Frikandelbroodje/main.py", line 56, in <module>
    dirk_price = get_price(dirk_url, dirk_classname)
  File "/home/cena/PycharmProjects/Frikandelbroodje/main.py", line 44, in get_price
    browser.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)
```

Answer (score 51):

### [invalid session id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID)

The **invalid session ID** error is a [WebDriver error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors) that occurs when the server does not recognize the unique session identifier. This happens if the *session has been deleted* or if the *session ID is invalid*.

A WebDriver session can be deleted through either of the following ways:

- [Explicit session deletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID#Explicit_session_deletion): A WebDriver session is explicitly deleted when explicitly invoking the `quit()` method as follows:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSessionIdException

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    print("Current session is {}".format(driver.session_id))
    driver.quit()
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Current session is a9272550-c4e5-450f-883d-553d337eed48
    No active session with ID a9272550-c4e5-450f-883d-553d337eed48
    ```
- [Implicit session deletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID#Implicit_session_deletion): A WebDriver session is implicitly deleted when you close the last window or tab invoking `close()` method as follows:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    print("Current session is {}".format(driver.session_id))
    # closes current window/tab
    driver.close()
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Current session is a9272550-c4e5-450f-883d-553d337eed48
    No active session with ID a9272550-c4e5-450f-883d-553d337eed48
    ```

---

### Conclusion

As the first one request works fine but for others you get a *session ID* error most possibly the *WebDriver* controled *Web Browser* is getting detected and hence blocking the next requests.

There are different reasons for the *WebDriver* controled *Web Browser* to get detected and simultaneously get blocked. You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [How does recaptcha 3 know I'm using selenium/chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835)
- [Selenium and non-headless browser keeps asking for Captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123142/selenium-and-non-headless-browser-keeps-asking-for-captcha/56136820#56136820)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I'll look into those discussions!

Answer (score 10):

I got this error message because I was running Selenium in docker and I hadn't mounted enough swap memory, so it would crash after just a few pages.

To fix this, I used the same docker command, but added `-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm` after docker run.

If you had this

```bash
docker run -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

then change to this

```bash
docker run -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

I found this info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62662360/5783745), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxbvFiYxEzI&t=4838s).

This will give the docker container more swap memory. From `docker run --help` it says:

```
-v, --volume list                    Bind mount a volume
    --volume-driver string           Optional volume driver for the container
    --volumes-from list              Mount volumes from the specified container(s)
```

In simple terms, I think it's telling docker it's okay for the container to use your host (i.e. your laptop's) memory.

Comment: if possible, can you quick explain what that addition does?

Comment: @Lounge9 Added some additional info to the answer (but the tl;dr is the -v option is telling docker it's fine for it to go ahead and use some of your laptop's memory).

Answer (score 3):

Browser page crash may leads to InvalidSessionIdException. Selenium says to us: `session deleted because of page crash`. Check if your browser page still exists when you got your errors.

Here an example of a traceback of this case:

```
[2021-06-28 15:05:43,787: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Message: invalid session id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 580, in find_elements_by_class_name
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

If you want some technical details, take a look at [Chromium sources](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/d7da0240cae77824d1eda25745c4022757499131/chrome/test/chromedriver/commands.cc#L265) where you can find string `session deleted because of page crash`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the reason was that I wrote url in wrong format - not like this, which is correct:

```
self.driver.get('https://twitter.com')
```

But this way:

```
self.driver.get('twitter.com')
```

Maybe you had the same issue. If not, just check all the links and make sure that all of them are in format of the correct one

Answer (score 0):

in mycase the issue I executed `driver.close()`  then tried to access current_url property of driver which is already closed

this what my wrong code leads to this error message:

```
url = 'http://localhost:5000/traning'
webpage = driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
return driver.current_url
```

this returns error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid
> session id

and this is solution just save current url and all data in variable before close driver to return this data

```
driver = setDriver()
url = 'http://localhost:5000/traning'
webpage = driver.get(url)
current_url = driver.current_url
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
return current_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.get('url')
#some code
current_page = driver.current_url
driver.close()
driver.quit()
time.sleep(10)
driver.get(current_page)
```

After I put driver.close with driver.quit it solve same issue, as you have

Answer (score 0):

After closing the driver you have to reinitialize it in order to make it start again.

```
chrome_driver_path = "D:\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://google.com/")

driver.close()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```