# Selenium server parallel tests error: invalid session id

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, parallel-processing

Hi can somebody tell me please what am I doing wrong in running parallel tests on Selenium server?
I have this simple parallel tests in the class:

```
package tests;

import categories.Category1;
import com.google.code.tempusfugit.concurrency.ConcurrentTestRunner;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ConcurrentTestRunner.class)
@Category(Category1.class)
public class ParalelTest extends Base
{
    protected String siteUrl = "/waitforit.php";

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        driver.get(baseUrl + siteUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("test1() thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("test2() thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void test3()
    {
        System.out.println("test3() thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void test4()
    {
        System.out.println("test4() thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Here is the screen with error:
[image]

What is wrong with that? Without server it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
```

...implies that the *chromedriver=80.0* wasn't able to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* with *Chrome Browser v80.0*.

---

Your main issue is the **version incompatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Though you are using latest *Selenium Client* version *3.141.59*, *Chrome Driver* version *80.0* and *Chrome* version *v80.0*.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_65** which is pretty **ancient**.

---

### Solution

A generic solution would be to:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent level of [JDK 8u241](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Update

However, the **invalid session ID** error is a [WebDriver error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors) that occurs when the server does not recognize the unique session identifier. This happens if the *session has been deleted* or if the *session ID is invalid*.

A WebDriver session can be deleted through either of the following ways:

- [Explicit session deletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID#Explicit_session_deletion): A WebDriver session is explicitly deleted when explicitly invoking the `quit()` method.
- [Implicit session deletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID#Implicit_session_deletion): A WebDriver session is implicitly deleted when you close the last window or tab invoking `close()` method.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id using Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483403/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-invalid-session-id-using/56492149#56492149)

Comment: I will try it.  But if I run this tests in one thread it works well....

Comment: I did update of Java JDK but the problem was not in Java but in static WebDriver which causes missing session id if some test close and quite the driver.

Comment: @Čamo Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: First part is not true. It was not version incompatibility. Remove it and it could be accepted.