# invalid session id error using Selenium through PHPUnit

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, phpunit

I'm tring to use Selenium for PHPUnit. But for first attempt, something went wrong.

I have error "invalid session id" in PHPUnit, but Selenium logs says, that everything is fine. Full text of error:

```
{stacktrace=#0 0x55c2598402d3 <unknown>, error=invalid session id, message=invalid session id}
```

What I did.

1. Has installed php 7.3:

   ```
   apt install php7.3
   ```
2. Installed Java:

   ```
   apt install default-jdk
   ```
3. Downloaded Chrome Driver ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138
4. Downloaded Selenium server stanalone

Now I understood, that I dowloaded wrong version of Selenium Server.

- Wrong: selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar
- Right: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar and higher.

Answer (score 0):

You may be still facing the same [invalid session id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492149/7429447) error as:

- You still seem to be using *ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138*
- Presumably you are using the latest *chrome=104.0*

So there is a clear mismatch between *chrome=104.0* and the *chromedriver=81.0.4044.138*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.4.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v104.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=104.0* (as per [chromedriver=104.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/notes.txt)).