# InvalidSessionIdException when restarting Selenium webdriver after closing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

In order to manage ReCAPTCHA, I've tried following exception:

```
try:
    #some code
except:
    print('recaptcha')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
    #Verify that command has been executed
    print('Closed')
    #restart webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options = options)
    #recursive call of function
    return parser(link, driver = driver)
```

Also tried with `implicitly.wait` instead `time.sleep`. However, `drive.close` command falling with `InvalidSessionIdException`.

```
try:
    #some code
except InvalidSessionIdException
    print(e.message)
```

The above solution proposed in [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id using Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56483403) doesn't work for me and coming to infinite loop of exceptions. Other solutions from that question have the same logic that my code.
Here is the traceback.

```
File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:551, in WebDriver.close(self)
    543 def close(self) -> None:
    544     """Closes the current window.
    545 
    546     :Usage:
   (...)
    549             driver.close()
    550     """
--> 551     self.execute(Command.CLOSE)

File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:440, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    438 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    439 if response:
--> 440     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    441     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    442     return response

File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:245, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    243         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
```

I could close driver with `driver.quit()` and then launch again, but in this case the process fails with the same error on the `driver.get(url)` step.

Answer (score 0):

[Invalid session ID - WebDriver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID)

You might have already closed your driver before you ran `driver.close()`.

Comment: No, I`v checked visually driver not in headless mode.