Seleniumbase stopped while using multiple authenticated proxies in multi-threading on Ubuntu
I am working on building a large scraper where I need to interact with the target website search some filenames solve captchas using capsolver API and append data to Google Sheets. My target is to pull 15k records daily. I am using concurrent.futures for multithreading. When I run the code initially it works fine but when it exceeds 1500 records it keeps slowing down and eventually stops with the following exception:
[selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id using Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483403/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-invalid-session-id-using) 
My downloads_files folder gets polluted with a lot of proxy files but that's okay as @mdmintz explained that it will generate proxy_ext_dir_0 etc files. But I don't know why it stopped eventually. Here is my code:
code explanation: What I am doing here is I input starting_file_number and ending_file_number the script will divide the number ranges and give them to every instance and if IP block it will call get_new_driver() function to get a fresh driver with a new proxy.
If someone faced this issue before please help me.
  def get_new_driver():
    proxy = proxy_rotator.get_next_proxy()
    return Driver(uc=True, headless=True, multi_proxy=True, proxy=proxy, no_sandbox=True, block_images=True)


   def run_scraper(starting_file_number, end_file_number):

    current_file_number = starting_file_number
    driver = get_new_driver()

    # Only for Debugging
    # timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    # filename = f"screenshot_{timestamp}.png"

    try:
        driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(SITE_URL, 10)

        csv_file = 'entity_details2.csv'

        while current_file_number <= end_file_number:
            try:
                search_entity(driver, current_file_number)

                form_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'form'))
                )
                form_text = form_element.text

                if 'Please complete the reCAPTCHA' in form_text:
                    handle_recaptcha(driver, CAPSOLVER_API_KEY,
                                     SITE_KEY, SITE_URL)
                    search_entity(driver, current_file_number)

                result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tblResults'))
                )
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tblResults tr'))
                )

                # After ensuring rows are present, get them
                rows = result.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr')[
                    1:]  # Exclude the first row

                for row in rows:
                    td = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')
                    td.click()

                    entity_details = scrape_entity_details(driver)
                    print(entity_details)
                    if entity_details:
                        append_to_csv(entity_details, csv_file)

                    driver.back()

                    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located(
                            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tblResults'))
                    )
                current_file_number += 1
            except Exception as e:

                # Only for Debugging
                # timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                # filename = f"screenshot_{timestamp}.png"
                # source_filename = f"screenshot_{timestamp}"
                # Take a screenshot and save it with the dynamic filename
                # driver.save_screenshot(filename)

                print(f"An error occurred for file number {
                      current_file_number}: {e}")

                msg = driver.title + ' Custpm Message'
                logger.warning(msg=msg)
                # if '502 Bad Gateway' in driver.title:
                driver.quit()
                driver = get_new_driver()
                print('Getting new driver...')
                driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(SITE_URL, 10)
                continue

    finally:
        driver.quit()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Number of concurrent scrapers you want to run
    num_workers = 3

    # Define ranges for different instances
    # start_file_number = 4618981
    # end_file_number = 4623981

    start_file_number, end_file_number = get_file_numbers()
    range_size = (end_file_number - start_file_number + 1) // num_workers

    file_number_ranges = [
        (start_file_number + i * range_size,
         start_file_number + (i + 1) * range_size - 1)
        for i in range(num_workers)
    ]

    # Ensure the last range extends to the end file number
    file_number_ranges[-1] = (file_number_ranges[-1][0], end_file_number)

    print(Fore.CYAN + "File number ranges for each worker:", file_number_ranges)

    # Execute the scrapers
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(run_scraper, start, end)
                   for start, end in file_number_ranges]

        for future in futures:
            future.result()

    print("All scraping instances are done!")

